# How can I boost a Bluetooth signal through a window?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm working on a project that involves a computer inside an office building connecting to a number of Bluetooth buttons outside of the office. The computer sits in a windowsill, so it's about as close to the buttons as it can get without being outside.

Upon testing the setup, we found that the buttons would stay connected from just about any position inside the office, but once we moved outside, the range dropped dramatically, the point where we could only operate them if we were a few feet from the window with the computer in it.

What are my options for increasing the range to get past the window? Is there some sort of "repeater" device that exists, that maybe we could install just outside the window?

Comment: Pro tip, gently break the window.

Comment: USB Bluetooth adapter + USB cable + drill = profit. Bonus points for using USB C because you can use a smaller drill.

Comment: I should mention that, while we have discussed drilling, we aren't authorized to make that decision so non-destructive solutions are ideal. Not that we won't ask...